# How to open and read VSCode's debugger trace file ("Error: Could not find an importer for the provided eventData.")

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, trace, vscode-debugger

I have the following `launch.json` for debugging a web app:

```
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/build/",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "trace": true
    }
```

When I set `"trace": true`, VSCode debugger produces a trace file that is stored at `Library/Application Support/Code/logs/.../window1/exthost/ms-vscode.js-debug/vscode-debugadapter-*.json.gz` on my Mac.

First, it is difficult to unzip it as any util throws some version of `unexpected end of file` error:

```
$ cat vscode-debugadapter-cfcd5cf7.json.gz| gzip -d > log.json
gzip: (stdin): unexpected end of file
```

Second, I tried to "Load" it anyway using `chrome://tracing` but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

How to open it that file? How people normally read it (because reading it raw is hardly possible). I can't get any decent information about it.

Answer (score 0):

To analyse the trace output of the VS Code PWA (Progressive Web Apps) debugger you can use the tool provided by Microsoft in this project (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pwa-analyzer)

You can start the tool directly from this website:

https://microsoft.github.io/vscode-pwa-analyzer/index.html